# How to change the InAppnitification's coming in direction?

Tags: uwp, windows-community-toolkit

Currently when `Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.InAppnitification` shows up, it always comes from botttom to top. But it's weird when I set the `InAppnitification`'s `VerticalAlignment` to `Top`.

So is there any example to redefine it's coming in direction.

[image]

Also, I have post a [feature request](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues/3302) on Github. If you want it, please vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/inappnotification) of InAppnitification, there are two properties: **HorizontalOffset** and **VerticalOffset**. They controls the horizontal and vertical offset of the popup animation, you can change them to redefine the notification's popup direction. For example:

**From Top to Bottom:**

```
<controls:InAppNotification x:Name="ExampleInAppNotification"
                            Content="This is a test message."
                            ShowDismissButton="True"
                            AnimationDuration="00:00:00.1000000"
                            VerticalOffset="-100"
                            HorizontalOffset="0"
                            StackMode="Replace" />
```

**From Left to Right:**

```
<controls:InAppNotification x:Name="ExampleInAppNotification"
                            Content="This is a test message."
                            ShowDismissButton="True"
                            AnimationDuration="00:00:00.1000000"
                            VerticalOffset="0"
                            HorizontalOffset="-100"
                            StackMode="Replace" />
```

**From Right to Left:**

```
<controls:InAppNotification x:Name="ExampleInAppNotification"
                            Content="This is a test message."
                            ShowDismissButton="True"
                            AnimationDuration="00:00:00.1000000"
                            VerticalOffset="0"
                            HorizontalOffset="100"
                            StackMode="Replace" />
```